# using switch in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, switch-statement

Switch is not finding my key.  I've tried with and without converting to string but still no luck.... what am I doing wrong?

```
var fromTWIL = "i want my key";

console.log(String(fromTWIL));
console.log(String(fromTWIL.match(/key/)[0]));

function extractKEY(ft){
    var rx = /key/g;
    var arr = rx.exec(extractKEY);
    return arr[0];
};
console.log(extractKEY(fromTWIL));
var key = extractKEY(fromTWIL);
   console.log("@"+key+"@");

switch (String(fromTWIL)){
    //case fromTWIL.match(/key/g)[1]:
    case String(fromTWIL.match(/key/g)[0]):
    //case extractKEY(fromTWIL):
    //case key:

        console.log('matched key');
    break;
    default:

        console.log('matched default');
    break;
};
```

Comment: Well the value of `fromTWIL` is that complete string, and the value of the `.match()` call will be just `"key"`, so they don't match. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You should use an `if` statement instead of a `switch` for this.

Comment: you should switch to if